# UICollectionView and willDisplayCell/SupplementaryView in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

As I see in documentation the methods:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplaySupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

Are available from ios8, I need to perform some actions then SupplementaryView will begin displayed in iOS7. How can I achieve it?